# TYPO3 indexed search pagination not working

Tags: typo3, tx-indexed-search

I installed Indexed Search extension and used it normally. It can show the search result but if the there is pagination on search result page, those paging buttons "Page 1, page 2,... next" not working. When i click on those paging buttons, it go to blank page.

Here's the template i use indexed search:

```
          <!-- Search -->
          <div class="search-wrapper">
            <div class="header-inner-right">
              <ul class="menu-icons-list">
                <li class="menu-icons">
                  <i class="menu-icons-style search search-btn fa fa-search"></i>

                  <form class="search-form" method="post" id="tx_indexedsearch" action="index.php?id=103">
                    <div class="tx-indexedsearch-hidden-fields">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[_sections]" value="0">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[_freeIndexUid]" id="tx_indexedsearch_freeIndexUid" value="_">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[pointer]" id="tx_indexedsearch_pointer" value="0">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[ext]" value="">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[stype]" value="1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[defOp]" value="0">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[media]" value="-1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[order]" value="rank_flag">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[group]" value="flat">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[lang]" value="-1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[desc]" value="0">
                      <input type="hidden" name="search[results]" value="30">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group animated fadeInDown">
                      <input type="search" name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]" value="" placeholder="Start searching ..." class="search-bar animated fadeIn form-control tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword sword">
                      <span class="input-group-btn" style="display: none">
                          <input type="submit" name="tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][submitButton]" value="Go" class="btn-u">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </form>


                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tx-indexedsearch-rules,
.tx-indexedsearch-searchbox {
  display: none;
}

.tx-indexedsearch-res {
  table {
    tbody {
      tr:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My search result page got id = 103. When i click to paging buttons, it goes to page 103 with blank content.

Comment: Your Indexed Search plugin installed on page id=103 ?

Comment: Yes I am. I got the search on sticky header, does it conflict with the search input on search page?

Answer (score 0):

A blank page usually indicates a fatal error in PHP. Inspect your logs.